# Mining drops to 0 H/s for hour

Tags: cpu-mining, mining

I am mining monero by xmr-stak-cpu on pool pool.supportxmr.com:5555. My problem is that hashrate sometimes crash to 0 H/s for about hour while CPU usage still be about 99%.

[image: Hashrate at time]

At the time in log appears

```
[2017-10-23 20:10:51] : Result rejected by the pool.
[2017-10-23 20:10:51] : Your miner was unable to find a share in time. Either the pool difficulty is too high, or the pool timeout is too low.
[2017-10-23 20:10:51] : SOCKET ERROR - RECEIVE error: socket closed
[2017-10-23 20:10:51] : Pool connection lost. Waiting 10 s before retry (attempt 1).
[2017-10-23 20:11:01] : Connecting to pool pool.supportxmr.com:5555 ...
[2017-10-23 20:11:01] : Connected. Logging in...
[2017-10-23 20:11:01] : Difficulty changed. Now: 5000.
[2017-10-23 20:11:01] : New block detected.
```

Is there any option how to fix that?

Comment: Did you intend to post a log showing hash rate crashing to 0 for an hour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash rate dropping to 0 is as measured by the pool, not your miner. The pool hash rate can and usually is different from what your miner will display, because the hashrate on the pool side is estimated based on the hashes you have submitted.

Because the difficulty of the port you are on is a bit high for your CPU hash rate (I estimate from the graph your actual hash rate is between 30-40 hashes per second), this causes your CPU to not find a valid share for a while, which makes the pool believe that you are hashing at 0. This is also what is causing the timeout in your connection.

The solution for this would be to move to a lower difficulty port, then your hashrate graph will be more consistent and closer (but still not 100% accurate) to the hashrate displayed in your miner.